# Use main report data for table in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

Development IDE used : Jaspersoft Studio

I am trying to use main report datasource for table dataset by using the below expression but i am not getting any data.

Please advise on how to pass the datasource from report to table. I am new to jasper reports. Samples would be helpful.

JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.1  -->
<!-- 2017-07-18T10:42:15 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="62118ef8-810f-4b01-a13c-46539c328b0e">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="LendingTrustFee1_3_Json"/>
        <style name="Title" fontName="Arial Unicode MS" fontSize="14"/>
        <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial Unicode MS" fontSize="11"/>
        <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial Unicode MS" fontSize="11"/>
        <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial Unicode MS" fontSize="11" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
        <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Table 2_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Table 3_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Table 3_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Table 3_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <subDataset name="TableDataset" uuid="b931bf1c-7487-4583-8af0-254967fef65f">
            <queryString language="csv">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </queryString>
            <field name="ClientAndBenificiary" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ClientAndBenificiary]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="DepartmentNameOfLender" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[DepartmentNameOfLender]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="TrustNoJapanese" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TrustNoJapanese]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ContractSignDate" class="java.sql.Date">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ContractSignDate]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="TrustNo" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TrustNo]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ReportStartDate" class="java.sql.Date">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ReportStartDate]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="EndStartDate" class="java.sql.Date">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[EndStartDate]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ReportPeriod" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ReportPeriod]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Currency" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Currency]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ShowLoanValue" class="java.lang.Boolean">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ShowLoanValue]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ShowCleanPrice" class="java.lang.Boolean">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ShowCleanPrice]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ShowAccruedInt" class="java.lang.Boolean">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ShowAccruedInt]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ShowDirtyPrice" class="java.lang.Boolean">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ShowDirtyPrice]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="UDF1" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[UDF1]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="UDF2" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[UDF2]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ReportFrequency" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ReportFrequency]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="QtrReportStartDate" class="java.sql.Date">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[QtrReportStartDate]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="QtrReportEndDate" class="java.sql.Date">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[QtrReportEndDate]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Securities_No_Mon1_3" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Securities_No_Mon1_3]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Lending_Fee_Mon1_3" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Lending_Fee_Mon1_3]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Trust_Fee_Mon1_3" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Trust_Fee_Mon1_3]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Consumption_Tax_Mon1_3" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Consumption_Tax_Mon1_3]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Trust_Fee_Tax_Included_Mon1_3" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Trust_Fee_Tax_Included_Mon1_3]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="SectionType" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[SectionType]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <filterExpression><![CDATA[LEN($F{Securities_No_Mon1_3}) > 0]]></filterExpression>
        </subDataset>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <detail>
            <band height="322" splitType="Stretch">
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement x="-1" y="0" width="551" height="220" uuid="3aaf3c11-1464-432e-a55d-fef0a54cfdaa">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 3_TH"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 3_CH"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 3_TD"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="TableDataset" uuid="75b0fbb9-805b-4e97-86e2-9a2688aae1ff">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:column width="90" uuid="21ee4add-5a78-4c46-8ae3-1da6c6759a19">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 3_TD" height="30">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="575908d3-6ea1-4a84-a95c-985941866a21"/>
                                    <box>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Securities_No_Mon1_3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="90" uuid="b5f25971-4c63-4094-ab6a-102adb70593e">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 3_TD" height="30">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="aa37293c-1ffc-48d3-a3f2-32abc83ebcb8"/>
                                    <box>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Lending_Fee_Mon1_3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="80" uuid="96b8c9f2-b20f-4850-8702-aa4935cd496f">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 3_TD" height="30">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="0c059aad-8bf2-45c7-854f-c26bcdcbcb72"/>
                                    <box>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Trust_Fee_Mon1_3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="70" uuid="4c69cb0c-bcd8-46a5-9ccc-f284fa037f14">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 3_TD" height="30">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="89d56faf-0773-4b1b-9229-08e2322e7650"/>
                                    <box>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Consumption_Tax_Mon1_3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="170" uuid="1ff92af5-e2c2-4ab9-864a-73496dec702d">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 3_TD" height="30">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="170" height="30" uuid="1ecb2036-49d9-4337-b1de-2aa660e15bd6"/>
                                    <box>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Trust_Fee_Tax_Included_Mon1_3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                    </jr:table>
                </componentElement>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

Json Data:

```
[{"sectionType":"A","ClientAndBenificiary":"全国共済水産業協同組合連合会","DepartmentNameOfLender":"財務運用部 御中","TrustNoJapanese":"6018","ContractSignDate":"2013-04-23","TrustNo":"6018","ReportStartDate":"2016-07-01","EndStartDate":"2016-07-31","ReportPeriod":"2016-07-01から2016-07-31まで","Currency":"円","ShowLoanValue":"0","ShowCleanPrice":"0","ShowAccruedInt":"0","ShowDirtyPrice":"0","UDF1":"0.08","UDF2":"","ReportFrequency":"","QtrReportStartDate":"2016-07-01","QtrReportEndDate":"2016-08-01","Securities_No_Mon1_3":"JGB #289(10)Total","Lending_Fee_Mon1_3":"523645.000000000","Trust_Fee_Mon1_3":"174537.000000000","Consumption_Tax_Mon1_3":"13950.000000000","Trust_Fee_Tax_Included_Mon1_3":"188487.000000000","ReportLanguage":"ja","SectionType":"A"},{"sectionType":"A","ClientAndBenificiary":"全国共済水産業協同組合連合会","DepartmentNameOfLender":"財務運用部 御中","TrustNoJapanese":"6018","ContractSignDate":"2013-04-23","TrustNo":"6018","ReportStartDate":"2016-07-01","EndStartDate":"2016-07-31","ReportPeriod":"2016-07-01から2016-07-31まで","Currency":"円","ShowLoanValue":"0","ShowCleanPrice":"0","ShowAccruedInt":"0","ShowDirtyPrice":"0","UDF1":"0.08","UDF2":"","ReportFrequency":"","QtrReportStartDate":"2016-07-01","QtrReportEndDate":"2016-08-01","Securities_No_Mon1_3":"JGB #300(10)Total","Lending_Fee_Mon1_3":"268618.000000000","Trust_Fee_Mon1_3":"89529.000000000","Consumption_Tax_Mon1_3":"7148.000000000","Trust_Fee_Tax_Included_Mon1_3":"96677.000000000","ReportLanguage":"ja","SectionType":"A"},{"sectionType":"A","ClientAndBenificiary":"全国共済水産業協同組合連合会","DepartmentNameOfLender":"財務運用部 御中","TrustNoJapanese":"6018","ContractSignDate":"2013-04-23","TrustNo":"6018","ReportStartDate":"2016-07-01","EndStartDate":"2016-07-31","ReportPeriod":"2016-07-01から2016-07-31まで","Currency":"円","ShowLoanValue":"0","ShowCleanPrice":"0","ShowAccruedInt":"0","ShowDirtyPrice":"0","UDF1":"0.08","UDF2":"","ReportFrequency":"","QtrReportStartDate":"2016-07-01","QtrReportEndDate":"2016-08-01","Securities_No_Mon1_3":"JGB #305(10)Total","Lending_Fee_Mon1_3":"538950.000000000","Trust_Fee_Mon1_3":"179641.000000000","Consumption_Tax_Mon1_3":"14354.000000000","Trust_Fee_Tax_Included_Mon1_3":"193995.000000000","ReportLanguage":"ja","SectionType":"A"}]
```

I have added the JRXML and Json I am trying to load. When I pass dataSourceExpression in dataset I am getting only 2 rows but in source data there are three rows. Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

For displaying data in table component in Jasper we need to setup new data set apart from main report data set. we can write any dummy query in main report data set like 'select 1 from dual;' in case database is mysql.

Comment: Thanks Shrashti for the reply, I have added a dummy dataset similar to the main dataset. I am using Json or CSV as input and for both are not working.

Comment: I have added the JRXML and Json I am trying to load. When I pass dataSourceExpression in dataset I am getting only 2 rows but in source data there are three rows. Please help me to resolve this.